# Bullet to asterisk in a passwordField

Tags: javafx

Is it possible to change these bullets to asterisks in a passwordField? If so, how?
[image]

Answer (score 6):

The bullet is unfortunately hard coded in the `TextFieldSkin` but you can easily create a PasswordSkin by overriding the default, like this:

```
import com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TextFieldSkin;
import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

public class PasswordSkin extends TextFieldSkin {
    public PasswordSkin(TextField textField) {
        super(textField);
    }

    protected String maskText(String txt) {
        if (getSkinnable() instanceof PasswordField) {
            int n = txt.length();
            StringBuilder passwordBuilder = new StringBuilder(n);
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                passwordBuilder.append("*");

            return passwordBuilder.toString();
        } else {
            return txt;
        }
    }
}
```

To use it, call `setSkin` on your `PasswordField`:

```
PasswordField input = new PasswordField();
input.setSkin(new PasswordSkin(input));
```

Alternatively, instead of setting the skin manually, you can include the following in your stylesheet:

```
.password-field {
    -fx-skin: 'sample.PasswordSkin'
}
```

Make sure `sample.PasswordSkin` is updated to reflect the fully qualified class name of your skin. Now every Scene or Node that has the stylesheet loaded will not need to have the skin configured manually.

Comment: Note that in Java 9 the package name for `TextFieldSkin` changes to `javafx.scene.control.skin.TextFieldSkin` (and it becomes part of the public API).

Comment: If we call this method in run time for example in case of showing password ,it invokes this exception : 
 `Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TextFieldSkin.updateSelection(TextFieldSkin.java:391)
 at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TextFieldSkin.updateSelection(TextFieldSkin.java:391)`